# Flutter - How to change the rotation point of the Container widget?

Tags: flutter

I'm using the `transform` property of the `Container` widget to rotate it around the Z-axis ,
just like that :

```
transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(10 * pi/180)
```

in the following snippet:

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(

//            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0,horizontal: 10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(
              "assets/img/women.png",
            ),
            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          width: deviceSize.width,
          height: deviceSize.height,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 90.0),
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 15),
                  transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(10 * pi / 180)
                    ..translate(10.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        blurRadius: 20.0,
                        color: Colors.orange,
                        offset: Offset(5, 7),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Shopping Universe',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 60.0,
                      fontFamily: 'Piedra',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: AuthCard(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

How to change the rotation point and set it to the `center of gravity` of the `container` ?

I could reposition it after that using translate ,something like that `Matrix4.rotationZ(15 * pi/180)..translate(10.0)`

But i'm not happy with that method ,

Could someone help me please ?

Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you cannot, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c969b8af7b/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/container.dart#L454 - here `Transform` is used with the default pivot point

Comment: Yeah i see ,Thank you !

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the `Container` with a `Transform` widget and set `origin` property to whatever you wish.

If you want the `origin` to be in the center of the `Container`, you have to do something like `origin: Offset(containerWidth/2, containerHeight/2)`.

And as your `Container` doesn't have a specific height(only the width is known_same as its parent), you have to find its size. You can use `RenderBox` for that. [Here](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-widget-size-and-position-b0a9ffed9407) you can find a tutorial on how to achive this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'auth_card.dart';
import 'dart:math' as Math;

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  GlobalKey _containerKey = GlobalKey();
  Size _containerSize = Size(0, 0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);
    super.initState();
  }

  Size _getSize() {
    final RenderBox renderBoxRed =
    _containerKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    return renderBoxRed.size;
  }

  _afterLayout(_) {
    _containerSize = _getSize();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(

//            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0,horizontal: 10.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(
                  "assets/img/women.png",
                ),
                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              width: deviceSize.width,
              height: deviceSize.height,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(10 * Math.pi / 180),
                      origin: Offset(
                          _containerSize.width / 2, _containerSize.height / 2),
                      child: Container(
                        key: _containerKey,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 15),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                          color: Colors.orange,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              blurRadius: 20.0,
                              color: Colors.orange,
                              offset: Offset(5, 7),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          'Shopping Universe',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 60.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Piedra',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: AuthCard()
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But note that:

> Setting an origin is equivalent to conjugating the transform matrix by a translation. This property is provided just for convenience.

Comment: Thank you ! I played around with  `Offset` already but , i can't get the exact coordinate to get it done , Can you please provide more clarification ?

Comment: OK, what do you mean by the centre of gravity?

Comment: rotating the Container around its centre instead of an other points (one of its edges for example). see this 
 https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/docs/documents/1328/geometric_sections_oblique_rectangle-Model.png

You see the 'O' point ?

Comment: Are the dimensions of the container known or they will be determined at the runtime?

Comment: Post edited , you can take a look 
As you see the parent Conatiner takes the full width and height of the screen  `width: deviceSize.width,` , `height: deviceSize.height` but i don't want to rotate it arround the center of the screen insteaf of rotate it arround itself .

Comment: I've updated the answer. If you specify the size of the container, the code would be much simpler.